# "Couldn't have got used to"

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Is the construction in bold correct in this sentence:

> It was changed just a month after you had joined, so you **couldn't have got used** to that too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You couldn't have got used to* is fine, but in US speech it would be *gotten*, and I think in conversation you'll more likely hear *You couldn't have gotten **too** used to that*. We try to keep modifiers as close as possible to the terms they modify.

Assuming that they're co-referent, I'd flip the *that* and the *it*, or make both pronouns *it*. The *that* points to something outside the sentence, so it should come first; it then  establishes a convenient referent for *it*.

The perfect construction in the first clause is unnecessary as it stands—see [**here**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/) and other questions under the [**past perfect**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-perfect) tag. Simple past will do:

> It was changed just a month after you joined, so you couldn't have gotten too used to it.

But if you flipped the two time references it the perfect would be just dandy:

> You had only been here a month when that changed, so you couldn't have gotten too used to it.

Comment: Stoney, you raised a good point. It seems to be an American thing to use *gotten*, instead of *got*.

Comment: @Tristan Yes; it contrast with *have got* which means "have in my possession".

Answer (score -1):

> Is the construction in bold correct in this sentence?

Yes. There is nothing wrong with it. Why would you think that there was? Using the word *got* like that, is correct in England and the rest of the UK.