# Was kidnapped Vs. had been Kidnapped

Tags: sentence-construction

> The police used a messaging app to search for the parents of a
>   seven-month old boy who ***was kidnapped*** from Azad Maidan on
>   Wednesday.

Why has the reporter used *was* instead of *had been*?

It should be:

> The police used a messaging app to search for the parents of a
>   seven-month old boy who ***had been kidnapped*** from Azad Maidan on Wednesday .

### Justification

*Had been* (the past perfect) is used to describe an action that happened *in past in past*. In the above sentence, the first activity was *kidnapping* and the second activity was *sending the message*. Hence, the reporter should use *had been*, but instead he used *was*. Please explain.

### Actual Activity

Wednesday morning  ---> Boy was kidnapped

Wednesday afternoon  ---> Police used messaging app to search for parents

### Reported speech

Wednesday morning  ---> Boy had been kidnapped

Wednesday afternoon  ---> Police used messaging app to search for parents

Comment: The principle here is [*don't use Past Perfect unless you really have to*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/126). Simple Past is fine in this context.

Answer (score 1):

We use the past perfect when we want to make an emphasis on referring to an action that occurred before another action in the past. However, in this statement both of the actions are so closely related that whether we use was kidnapped or had been kidnapped, there occurs no change in the meaning. There are many cases where we can use either the past simple or the past perfect, without any difference in meaning, such as "he went to the counter after he filled or had filled the basket. It sounds good if we avoid the use of the past perfect where the past simple will do. So it sounds more natural if we use was kidnapped in this statement.

Answer (score 1):

"Had been kidnapped" implies that the kidnapping happened but is now over, specifically "had been" says that the existence of the state (of being kidnapped) is now in the past, ergo, the kidnapping is now over.

"Was kidnapped" states that this happened without further implication as to whether the state has changed again.