# what is the difference between "You could have experience in a bakery" and "You could have experience in bakery"

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

I was reading my previous question last night:
[Should you use present or past tense when telling people about your work experience?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64124/should-you-use-present-or-past-tense-when-telling-people-about-your-work-experie)

And I saw Jay write this:

> You could have experience "in a bakery", as opposed to "in bakery"

I would like to know whether these two sentences have different meaning:

> You could have experience "in a bakery"
>
> You could have experience "in bakery".

if yes, could you tell me why please?

Comment: You will never now hear a person say **"You could have experience in bakery".** it's archaic already.

Comment: You have baking experience from working in a bakery.  But if you did their financial accounting, say, and have no hands-on experience making bread and cakes, then we wouldn't say that you had "baking experience". Then you would have some "bakery experience".  You know how a bakery operates but might not know how to bake a cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the noun **"bakery"** has an out-dated definition which means **"the art of baking"** and **"a bakery"** is a place where baking is done, where people cook bread or other things.

- *You could have experience "in a bakery"* means in a place where they bake. a building.
- *You could have experience "in bakery"* means in the science of baking.

Comment: That said, you could use a gerund: _You could have experience in **baking**._ And you could use the original construct with words that are still in use: _You could have experience in medicine._