# "have been" or "were" in this context

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I wrote this sentence:

> We suppose that two items are similar if they have been bought together by many people.

Should I say?

> We suppose that two items are similar if they were bought together by many people

That sentence is the premise of a theory, it is a fact, not opinion.

item means product in this context

Comment: @Cardinal like we assume that two products are similar if many users bought them together. got me please ?

Comment: @Cardinal that is a theory we are trying to check. the thing is not in the meaning of the sentence but in the grammar, don't worry about the truth (validity) of the sentence, that is what we are proving

Comment: @Cardinal great, thanks man, is it clearer now ?

Comment: that should be a face so it is always true, not just in the past or in the future, it is always true. but the buying action is in the past of course

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is you would want to say something like this: "Two items are considered similar provided that many people buy them together"

Comment: similar in this context, doesn't mean similar by content, but "my similar" for example, people buy wine and cheese, so they are "similar" but less people buy "laptop and bread" together, (you don't get out of the store having laptop and bread) you got me guys ?

Comment: @AlanCarmack I do not see any conditional sentences on that link.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - Please read this [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/13262#13262) and decide whether you need to use the perfect here. Note the bolded advice: "Don't use the perfect unless you need it." Or try FumbleFingers's [answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/37009). Either one will help you.

Answer (score -1):

> **We suppose that** two items are similar **if** they were* bought together by
>   many people.

You only 'suppose' if you have evidence to support a supposition. So when put together, these bolded statements make sense. 'If' is the modifier here. Your supposition only exists because of the word 'if.'

*You use 'were' in more affirmative statements. It it like subjunctive, but not quite - since English has no subjunctive, truly. It only has it in some cases. It is suitable for proving theory, since it implies you know that if products are bought together, they [then/therefore] are similar.

- You use 'have been' in more present situations. If things are being
  bought *right now, right here, in this moment,* then it is
  appropriate to use 'have been.' It's a more hypothetical case. It
  means you only suppose your supposition if the following (buying
  products) has occurred. If it hasn't, then you don't suppose
  anything. You continue on supposing that they're dissimilar, until
  they are bought together.