# Past Perfect: Had

Tags: past-perfect

Is the auxiliary verb "had" needed in this sentence?

Amy from finance ***had emailed*** me an approval form to fill out.  I sent it back last week.

or

Amy from finance ***emailed*** me an approval form to fill out.  I sent it back last week.

Comment: In your scenario, past perfect is not necessary and simple perfect is fine since the order of events is understandable.

Comment: Twice in an hour, we have the opportunity to offer the wisdom: [**Don't use the perfect unless you have to!**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/37009)