# How do I chose the correct tense usage?

Tags: past-perfect, tense-agreement

> It was Kuchela's friendship rather than his friendship  that **drove him** to Krishna's side.

Could it be **had driven him**?

> You **told** me yesterday.

Could it be **had told**?

Comment: You ask how to choose the "correct" tense, but the perfect is not "incorrect" in either of your sentences. You _can_ use the perfect in both cases. The question is, why do you need to use it? What do you think the perfect expresses that the simple past does not?

Comment: Why shouldn't we use it? The sentences in both cases will be synonyms?

Comment: The question is "Why is it necessary to use the perfect?" A good principle is [**Don't use Past Perfect unless you really have to.**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/37009) What does "You _had told_ me yesterday" express that is not expressed by just "You told me yesterday"?

Comment: We would only need the past perfect if it were necessary to describe the past event explicitly from the perspective of _another_ time in the past: _"Dave realized later that it was Pradeep's friendship rather than his own that **had driven him** to Oscar the Grouch's side."_ In your sentence, the simple past is all that is needed.