# problem with present perfect and simple past

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I failed to understand the difference between two sentences mentioned below.

a) My father has worked at this company for 35 years.

b) My father worked at this company for 35 years.

Comment: See [the canonical post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/27840) about present perfect. Not a short answer, but a correct one.

Comment: _"My father has worked at this company for 35 years"_ suggests that the work started 35 years ago and continues to the present. _"My father worked at this company for 35 years"_ tells us nothing about when the work began, but suggests that it is completed. (It's wise to observe the advice [**Don’t use the perfect unless you need it**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/37009))

Answer (score 1):

> My father has worked at this company for 35 years.

Means that he worked at the company for 35 years and he is still working there. Alternatively, you can say *My father has been working at this company for 35 years*

> My father worked at this company for 35 years

Means that he used to work at the company but he is no longer working there now.