# Translating into English correctly (boiling down to Past Perfect usage matters)

Tags: past-perfect

This is the example of the text which needs to be checked out:

> A: Is he a student?
>
> B: Yes, he studies at our university. He worked at our factory before
>   he entered our university. Now he doesn't work.

Thus, I used **`worked`** instead of **`had worked`**. I did it because the **`process of working`** is a habitual, permanent state in the past and now it's not connected with the current situation: **`Now he doesn't work.`**

Since it's no longer valid I could use **`used to work`** as well as the above variant, but not Past Perfect.

As far as I understand, the **`process of entering the university`** is a reference time; some point or may be past time to which he worked at the factory.

So, am I right? Is my understanding of the case correct?

Comment: He is a student at the university now but used to work in a factory. He *isn't working* there any longer.

Comment: A prosecutor might ask him: ***Did** you ever **do** any factory work before entering the university?* OR ***Had** you ever **done** any factory work before entering the university?* the latter only if the prosecutor wished to draw *special attention* to the chronology, which is already abundantly clear with **before**. In other words, you can make **entering the university** a reference time in the past or not.  It is not whether it is or isn't one, but *whether you wish to make it one*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my ear, "used to" is not well qualified by a *before* phrase or an *until* phrase.

> Before getting an expensive speeding ticket, he **used to drive** like a madman.
>    <sup>less idiomatic</sup>
>
> Before getting an expensive speeding ticket, he **drove** like a madman.
>   <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> He **used to drive** like a madman before he got a speeding ticket.   <sup>less idiomatic</sup>
>
> He **drove** like a madman before he got a speeding ticket. <sup>idiomatic</sup>
>
> He **used to drive** like a madman until he got a speeding ticket.  <sup>less idiomatic</sup>
>
> He **drove** like a madman until he got a speeding ticket. <sup>idiomatic</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, but it depends on what you want to say.  "Now he doesn't work" is disconnected from the previous information so it means, "He's unemployed," and not, "He doesn't work at our factory anymore".

If that's what you mean to say, "used to" is appropriate:

> "He used to work at our factory before he entered our university"

I'm a little confused, though, since none of the verbs in your example is past perfect.

Answer (score -3):

Past Perfect is used to  tell something which had happened before something specific happened ,  therefore, Past Perfect should be used here. And Simple Past can only be used (with before / after clauses) if the action in past perfect was completed at a specific time.... e.g......"visited the Taj  Mahal once in 1993 before something happened."
..

Comment: Hey friends, Please tell where I am wrong.

Comment: There is no good reason to use the past perfect in the OP's context. See **[FumbleFingers' Perfect Truism.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/verb-tenses-when-asking-a-question/5666#5666)**

Comment: Also tell what is the meaning of OP?

Comment: Original Poster.