# What is the difference in meaning between these sentences?

Tags: sentence-meaning, past-perfect, past-simple

> - They **had cooperated** closely in the planning of the project.
> - They **cooperated** closely in the planning of the project.

As I know, we usually use *had* when we want to specify that one event happened before the other. According to the first sentence what a change that *had* made to it?

Comment: I already know that, and that is what I am asking about. Because the first sentence mentioned in the oxford dictionary, and I want to know why is had mentioned? at the time he did not add other event.

Comment: @BavyanYaldo  The problem is that it's half the context.  As you guess you would not use "had" except to imply relationship to some other condition or event -- which doesn't have to be explicitly stated, but should be something the listener would know.

Comment: There is no difference in meaning between the two, only a difference in time perspective. We can't know from the context (we have none!) why (or whether) the speaker needs to place the completed action in the past. Understanding and using the perfect in English is something that takes practice for a new speaker of the language. A good basic rule (we call it **_[FumbleFingers' Perfect Truism](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/32)_**) is "Don't use Past Perfect unless you really have to".