# present simple or present perfect for this case

Tags: present-perfect

Our company **produced**   the car which Pope John Paul II used during his visit to South America last year.

Will it be possible to use present perfect if the company  still produces this car

Comment: Yes, but there would be little reason to do so unless you wanted to add a fact that establishes some relevance of the past production to the present moment, such as "*Since 1973*, our company has produced (or has been producing) the car which the pope used...".  There, "the car" would be understood to mean "the model".

Comment: It would be _possible,_ but not _necessary._ Put briefly, without other context (of the sort provided by Tᴚoɯɐuo, for instance) a native speaker would never use the present perfect here. If you want to delve more deeply into the perfect, have a go at **[this article.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/32)**