# What is the difference between "had engaged", "had been engaged", and "were engaged" in this context?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

> Prime Minister Narendra Modi disclosed on Saturday that the registration of over 1 lakh **companies which had allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions** post demonetisation had been scrapped as he sought to cast the goods and services tax (GST) as his second strike against black money and corruption.

Source:
[48 hrs before GST, 1 lakh cos lost registration for post-DeMon `lapses'](http://epaperbeta.timesofindia.com/Article.aspx?eid=31804&articlexml=PM-48-hrs-before-GST-1-lakh-cos-02072017001009) *The Times of India (Mumbai)*

Is this sentence construction is correct in above news?
Why Past perfect is used here?

> "companies which **had** allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions"

Or it can be

> "companies which **had** allegedly **been** engaged in suspicious transactions"

Or it can be

> "companies which **were** allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions"

Comment: It's hard to critique one part of the sentence when, overall, it's miserably bad writing.  Maybe it's grammatical, but not acceptable journalism.

Comment: @Andrew I don't think this is asking for a critique (which would be off-topic), but rather about understanding what tense is appropriate in a particular context. If it's incorrect, or correct but "bad writing", we should explain why. Maybe this journalist didn't have the benefit of the community here at ELL helping them ;)

Comment: I can't tell for sure but what I see from Ngram is that the trend is changing. I think I'm convinced that the passive form is grammatical but not necessary and the original is the best among the three variations.

Comment: If ever there was an exemplar of the gratuitous use of the past perfect...if he weren't still with us, F⚡️F would be spinning in his grave. In fact, all three are needlessly prolix. Is this guy paid by the word? _"companies which allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions"_ is all that is required. (And I'm not sure _allegedly_ is needed, come to that.)

Answer (score 1):

> Why [is the p]ast perfect [...] used here?

Because the main verb of the sentence--*disclosed*--is in the past tense and the (completed) actions described by the verbs *engage* and *scrap* occurred before that disclosure. As has been mentioned, the sentence is not written in the clearest manner possible. That said, its verb tenses are correct and bog standard.

To address the other options:

> ...had allegedly been engaged...

just adds another layer of opacity to the writing and either means (*a*) exactly the same thing as the terser phrasing or (*b*) means that some other entity was responsible for engaging these companies in suspicious transactions. Sense (*b*) doesn't seem supported by the rest of the context, so it's just making poor phrasing worse.

> ...were allegedly engaged...

similarly can mean (*a*) exactly the same thing as the past perfect or (*b*) shift it into the passive. Again, sense (*b*) doesn't seem supported. The difference between the first sense and the past perfect is that the same action is being described, but without reference to the occurrence of the main verb. It suggests a more distant relationship between the two verbs.

> He had asked her to marry him before she moved to Topeka.

places the question solidly before the completed action of her move to Topeka.

> He asked her to marry him before she moved to Topeka.

places the question in the past and removes any connection between the time of the two verbs, leaving it unclear whether she did in fact ever actually leave.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> Why Past perfect is used here?

In the sample of purple journatistic prose which you present, there are a number of possible explanations for the use of the *past perfect*. However, the most likely is not concerned with grammar: Either the writer wished to impress us with his command of English or he had a short character count and needed to increase it to fill the column.

Not a jot of information is added to the account of Mr Modi's action through the use of the past perfect. The "suspicious transactions" took place after demonetization (Mr Modi's removal of 500- and 1,000-rupee notes from circulation), so we already know when the companies *engaged* in these practices relative to the Saturday when Mr Modi made his announcement. There is no need to use the past perfect to tell us again.

Your other proposed verb forms are similarly unnecessary. The simple past is all we require here:

> *"...the registration of over 1 lakh **companies which engaged in suspicious transactions** post demonetisation had been scrapped..."*

<sup>(Note that I have also deleted *allegedly*, since it's obvious from the rest of the statement that wrongdoing is alleged.)</sup>

You will find on this site many learned explanations of the past perfect, replete with pictures of eyeballs facing this way and that and graphs demonstrating the relative positions of events on a temporal continuum. In many cases like this one, though, the simple past concisely and accurately expresses the relationship between events. If you are interested, [***FumbleFingers' Perfect Truism***](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/32) presents the worthwhile principle: *"Don't use the Perfect unless you really have to."*

Answer (score -2):

**Let's start with the past perfect:**

> "companies which had allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions"

Past perfect compares an action in the past which is completed prior to some other past point in time (which can be specified but also which can be implied).  See:

> past per·fect /ˈˌpast ˈpərfəkt/ adjective
>   1. (of a tense) denoting an action completed prior to some past point of time specified or implied, formed in English by had and the past
>   participle, as in he had gone by then.  - Google

In this case there is a simple past item, the *Prime Minister disclosed on Saturday* but, prior to this simple past item, there was an earlier past point or points where the *companies had allegedly engaged in suspicious transactions*.

**Second, let's look at the past perfect progressive/continuous:**

> "companies which had allegedly been engag[ing] in suspicious
>   transactions"

**please note the form changes from *engaged* to *engaging***

The [PAST PERFECT PROGRESSIVE TENSE](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/past_perfect_progressive.htm) *indicates a continuous action* that was completed at some point in the past; more precisely, [something that started in the past and continued up to another action or time in the past](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/past-perfect-continuous-use.html) (or else had finished just before another event in the past).

The change in meaning between the past perfect tense and the past perfect continuous tense is that, while the past perfect tense indicates that the companies had engaged in suspicious transactions at some points in the more distant past (but may have self-corrected that behavior so it could well be something that happened a few times 5-10 years ago but nothing more recent), the past perfect continuous tense would modify that meaning to indicate the companies had continued to actively engage in a pattern of suspicious transactions up to a point just before or even up to the point of the announcement by the Prime Minister.

**Third, let's look at the past progressive/continuous:**

> "companies which were allegedly engag[ing] in suspicious transactions"

**please note the form changes from *engaged* to *engaging***

The [past continuous](http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-continuous-tense/) describes actions or events in a time before now, which began in the past and is still going on at the time of speaking.  [Both past continuous and past perfect continuous tenses](https://www.englishgrammar.org/difference-continuous-perfect-continuous-tenses/) can be used to talk about actions or situations that were in progress at a certain point of time in the past. While the past continuous merely shows continuity, the past perfect continuous tense also puts an emphasis on the idea of duration. It is mainly used to indicate the duration of a past activity or state.

In this particular case, as in many cases, changing to the past continuous tense would modify the meaning from the past perfect in much the same way that changing to the past perfect continuous tense would modify that meaning.  The past continuous tense would modify that meaning to indicate the companies had continued to actively engage in a pattern of suspicious transactions up to the recent announcement by the Prime Minister.

**Final notes on grammar**

You will notice in a couple of instances above I changed *engaged* to *engaging* - it is necessary to use the participle form when using continuous tenses in active voice (passive voice is different).  Think about a similar set of sentences:

```
People who had run in the marathon.
People who had been run[ning] in the marathon.
People who were run[ning] in the marathon.
```

Maybe using this similar but different sentence will help you understand why *engaged* needs to change to *engaging* in the second and third examples.

**Edit**

Because @ColleenV seems to be struggling mightily with this [here](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/active-passive-voice-continuous-perfect-tense/) is some additional information about understanding Active and Passive Voices in Past Continuous and Past Perfect Tenses.  I hope the examples in this link along with the many I've already provided, including in my responses below, will help clarify this for anyone who is still struggling to understand it.

Past Continuous Tense

> Active sentences in the past continuous tense have the following
>   structure:
>
> **Subject + was/were + -ing form of the verb + object**
>
> Passive sentences in the past continuous tense have the following structure:
>
> **Object of the active sentence + was/were + being + past participle form of the verb + by + subject of the active sentence**

Comment: I'm not sure why you changed "had been engaged" to continuous. Would you explain a bit more why? Isn't "had been engaged in illegal behavior" grammatically OK?

Comment: @ColleenV I have a final section on grammar where I explain my thoughts on that.  If you replace *engaged* with *run* or another verb do you still think it's grammatically ok?  It would be ok in the passive, I agree, but I don't think it's ok here.  Can you comment on my **Final notes on grammar** section and let me know where you disagree?  I'm not sure I'm correct but I have laid out my thoughts for you so not sure why your question is posed as if I hadn't?

Comment: @ColleenV but to give further clarity, the working *had been engaged* would imply that a third party was doing the action, that a third party was actively engaging the companies and the companies were therefore passively, possibly unwillingly engaged.  So if the companies *had been fined* or *had been praised by the media* these are third party actions that the company is impacted by passively.  On the other hand, because the company is actually the actor, the correct word is *engaging* - now it's active not passive.  Companies *had been filing environmental reports*, for instance.

Comment: Here are a couple examples that I couldn't fit in my previous comment: [Over the previous couple years, Japan and the U.S. **had been engaged in** a tit-for-tat diplomatic and economic struggle...](http://mentalfloss.com/article/29434/planning-pearl-harbor). [...concealed that its Chief Executive Officer **had been engaged** in a purported pump-and-dump scheme.](https://www.stockwatch.com/News/Item.aspx?bid=U-z6821560-U%3aZPAS-20170628&symbol=ZPAS&region=U)

Comment: Here's a better example of why I'm confused: ["for something that started in the past and continued up to a given time in the past: When George died he and Anne **had been married** for nearly fifty years."](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/past-tense/past-perfect) Sorry I'm being frustratingly dense, but "being engaged in" is similar to "being married", and not similar to "running" or another verb that would require a continuous form. The continuous form can be used correctly, but I think the past perfect can as well with a slightly different nuance.

Comment: @ColleenV the action of marrying is done by a priest or judge or ship captain (and if religious, by God).  People who live in marriage are not marrying each other continuously they have been married by a third party.  On the other hand, they probably talked to each other - so *he and Anne had been talking for nearly fifty years* **not** *he and Anne had been talked for nearly fifty years*.  Engagement is also a one-time event, done to each other.  It is not a continuous action, though the state persists, sort of like planting a tree.  *The tree had been planted*.

Comment: Why do you ascribe to "google" the entry from the Oxford dictionaries site?

Comment: @P. E. Dant good question.  If you go to Google and google "past perfect" you will see right at the top a definition.  The definition says *Dictionary* but doesn't cite or link to *Oxford Dictionary*.  I was always taught to cite the source I pulled from, so if I pulled directly from the Google web page, without proceeding to another web page, then my source is Google, even if I suspect that Google might be regurgitating Oxford Dictionary.  Is this not the correct way to cite a source?

Comment: Do you really think _"Because @ColleenV seems to be struggling mightily"_ adds anything useful to this answer? There does seem to be a mighty struggle going on in the answer, but not on the part of ColleenV.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I trimmed a bunch of back and forth comments that lead up to that. (Although this is a good example of why answers shouldn't count too much on someone having read the comments)