# Past perfect with "after"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

My question is a short one. Do I always have to use past perfect after the word after? (when talking in past tense)

Take this sentence as an example: *After I had finished working, I did some shopping.*

Could I say this: *After I finished working, I did some shopping*. Without any difference in meaning?

Comment: I suggest you rely on the guiding principle we called [Fumblefingers' Perfect Truism: Don't use past perfect unless you really have to](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/verb-tenses-when-asking-a-question/5666#5666). The word 'after' is enough to indicate that one action took place before another in the past, so you don't have to employ past perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily:

After I finish working, I will go to the movies.

Perhaps with the past tense it is best to use the perfect to indicate the fact that the verb's action has been completed.