# The use of the present perfect and the past perfect in context

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-perfect

Tell me please which tense is the most apt to use in the following context.

> Rob, do you often drink soft drinks? I **haven't** thought about that.
>
> Rob, do you often drink soft drinks? I **hadn't** thought about that.

I heard native English speakers use the present perfect in similar contexts. But wouldn't it be more grammatically appropriate to use the past perfect. Because Rob hadn't thought about that before the other person asked him a question. If both sentence equally correct, explain me why please.

Comment: Most native speakers would use the ***Present Perfect*** form (#1 above) in such contexts, if only because it's a bit "simpler" than Past Perfect (#2) - and unlike learners, native speakers usually *avoid* using more complex tense forms if they have a choice. But *in principle* there's a semantic difference. Present Perfect implies *I still don't have any idea [and I may be unable to answer]*, whereas Past Perfect implies *[in response to your question] I've just given it some thought [and I'm about to give you my answer]*. In practice though, that's not normally a meaningful difference.

Comment: Is the response being given by Rob? It would be exceedingly strange for the same person to follow up their question with the second sentence. *That*, rather than *it*, also seems a bit odd.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I don't think it makes any difference whether the second sentence is a continuation from Rob or a response. For the purposes of differentiating Past and Present Perfect here, to the extent that there ***is*** a difference of nuance / idiomacy, it's the same issue regardless of who's speaking that line. And it's not *that* odd to mention that you never previously gave a thought to what someone else "often does", at the same time as actually asking them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Never use the perfect unless you really need it. ;-) Imo, _I never thought about it_ will do.

Comment: @MvLog: (*FumbleFingers' Perfect Truism*)[https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/126] Hoist by my own petard! To be honest, I reckon even if I did use what looks like "Simple Past" there, I'd be half-way to thinking I'd simply "elided / not enunciated" ***I've*** instead of plain ***I***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the *same* speaker is saying both sentences (asking a question and then answering themself), I would think twice about their mental stability. (Unless they were an actor rehearsing lines.) But the *context* of any dialogue is important to understanding how something should be phrased. The second sentence, in both cases, seems fine to me if it's an answer to a question. If it's the same person saying both sentences, it's not clear if it's an actual (non-rhetorical) question and an answer—despite the syntax.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I can't see anything unusual about asking a question about something *and* observing that you've never thought about that issue before, in the same utterance (regardless of which order you deliver the question and the observation in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M.Swan put it:

> In an informal style, simple past tenses are sometimes possible with
>   *always, ever* and *never* when they refer to 'time up to now'.
>   *I always*
>   *knew I could trust you.* (or *I've always known* ... )
>   *Did you ever see*
>   *anything like that before?* (or *Have you ever seen* ... ?)

The past perfect is of little use here unless it is used for the coordination of past events: *I had never thought about it until yesterday's accident.*