# Talking about a sequence of actions which happened in the past

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

For example, I want to tell how is my day was going.

I'd do it like this:

> I woke up, then I went to a bathroom and washed myself, then I went to a kitchen and had a breakfast, etc.

**Is it correct?** I mean maybe I need to use Past Perfect, because it's needed to use when I tell about actions in the Past before some other action in the Past?
**And how would native speaker tell about that sequence?**

Comment: That depends on whether they are leading up to another event, or just an uneventful description. For example "I had bathed and eaten breakfast, when there was a knock at the door..." Another way would be to use the present tense for dramatic effect: "I am eating breakfast and suddenly there is someone banging on the door..."

Comment: *The guiding principle [don't use Past Perfect unless you really have to*.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/126) I wrote that in the context of "Verb tenses when asking a question", but it applies more generally. Native speakers know perfectly well that you don't go to the bathroom until ***after*** you woke up, and you don't wash yourself until after you've gone to the bathroom, etc. Besides which, we usually list past activities *in the order in which they happened*, so we rarely "need" Past Perfect to tell us what sequence things happened in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Yes. But actually, unless he *wanted* to exaggerate the "list-like" quality, a native speaker would probably avoid several of the "optional" repetitions in your example. *I woke up, went to the bathroom and washed, then went to the kitchen and had breakfast* (note that some of your indefinite articles are completely non-idiomatic in this context).