# I was knit a sweater

Tags: passive-voice

Can *to knit* be used in this passive structure? The meaning I want this sentence to have is *Someone knit a sweater <strike>to</strike> for me*.

1. I was knit a sweater.

I know that *to give* can be used in this passive structure, for example:

▪︎ I was given a toy.

Comment: ***Knit** is one of the words that can remain the same in past, presence and future (called '**uninflected tense**'). **Knit** is an irregular verb, being that [the past participle word 'knitted' is also correct](https://preply.com/en/question/past-tense-of-knit). Use of the past tense verbs 'had' or 'have' is appropriate when the word sequence is '**had knit**' or '**have knit**' (which is past tense).*

Comment: Heh heh. That grammar of knitting is tangled.

Comment: See: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332112/i-was-cooked-fried-roasted-boiled-onions and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332107/i-was-shaven-my-moustache

Comment: I would more likely say this in the active voice: “Someone knitted a sweater for me” or “Someone knitted me a sweater.” Passive is grammatically correct too, though.

Comment: @Davislor but you would not say "Someone hitted me."

Comment: @RonJohn Correct: *hit* is an irregular verb, and there is no such word as \**hitted*. The third-person simple past tense of `*knit* can be either *knitted* or *knit*. , so OP’s use of *knit* was correct too. I am more likely to say *knit* as a past participle, personally, but that also can be either *was knitted* or *was knit*.

Comment: @RonJohn Or see FumbleFingers’ great answer.

Comment: @Davislor "some speakers will model the Past Tense after *He hit me yesterday*".  Exactly.  "Knit" sounds like "hit", so you use the same rules (except when you don't).

Comment: @RonJon Because it sounds like *sit*, the past tense should be *knat*? :)

Comment: @Davislor that's where "(except when you don't)" comes into force.

Comment: I'm not sure of the official grammar, but to me, "she knit me" or "I was knit a sweater" sounds like you're the object being knitted!

Answer (score 15):

[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knit#:%7E:text=Word%20forms%3A%203rd%20person%20singular,for%20meaning%20%5Bsense%204%5D.) unequivocally asserts that the Past *Participle* is always ***knitted***, but they have a "usage note" saying that ***knit*** as a Past *Tense* is acceptable in the context of *bones that knit together* (in the past).

I think Collins is simply *wrong*, and [here's a usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%20knit%20me%20a%2Cshe%20knitted%20me%20a%2Cbones%20have%20knit%2Cbones%20have%20knitted&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) to support my position...

[image]

There's nothing inherently wrong with using the passive as per OP's example, which (Collins notwithstanding) is perfectly valid using ***knit*** or ***knitted***. There's no doubt the verb is "defective", but some speakers will model the Past Tense after *He **hit** me yesterday* where others match it to *He **fitted** the catflap yesterday*.

---

Apologies for using an *image*, but [here's usingenglish.com...](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/knit.html)

[image]

---

...and here's a final word from [grammar.com...](https://www.grammar.com/knit_vs._knitted)

> *...officially and especially in UK English<sup>1</sup>, “knitted” is just as correct as “knit” in past tense, **both in past simple and in past participle**. Formed by adding “-ed” after doubling the last consonant, “knitted” is **equally frequently used** in the English vocabulary as “knit” in past tense, and there is **no restriction or context** that requires the use of one or the other version.*

---

<sup>1</sup> I have no evidence (or "gut feel") that there's any significant BrE/AmE usage split here, so I don't necessarily endorse *that* assertion.

Comment: No, the Collins does not unequivocally assert what you claim. The Collins says this: LANGUAGE NOTE:  
**The past tense can be either knit or knitted for meaning [sense 4]**.

Comment: That is *exactly* what I'm saying. But (1) - I don't accept that ***knit*** can ***only*** be a valid Past **Tense** with that specific meaning, and (2) - I'm happy to use ***knit*** as a Past **Participle** as well (which Collins doesn't endorse at all).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sorry for raising this storm, and well done for persevering with the issue. For my part, I had just chosen a dictionary so I was basing my answer on more than my own opinion. Next time, I'll hesitate before choosing Collins! Having read your answer, I agree with you fully :)

Comment: @PeterKirkpatrick: Ty, I appreciate the acknowledgement. But I can't deny that for *learners*, your answer is more suitable. It's a reversal of what *usually* happens with me on ELL (I say something is "too obscure" for most learners to bother with, and people wade in with *That's patronising! Learners should be told **everything**!*). But I just couldn't let the Collins assertions stand unchallenged, even if this wasn't the best place to shout the odds. I haven't gone into this in *maximum* detail yet, but it looks *possible* this is an irregular verb *gaining* traction (not "going extinct").

Comment: As a follow up question, I'm conscious that I'm relatively new to this site. Is there any sort of consensus or advice as to which ELL sources and authorities are best to use?

Comment: Collins is usually good, so I wouldn't take one "lapse" too much to heart. I have the feeling that the online edition leans more to *current* than historical usages - which is no bad thing for *most* learners (who are keen to learn and use English in the modern world), but not so good if you're trying to read classic English literature when it's not your mother tongue! Anyway, welcome to the club where you've obviously got off to a cracking start (in just a few weeks, I see). Check out [Resources for learning English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/) on meta.

Comment: Not sure if [this link to the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62893143#62893143) will work, but mod gotube says there *I think our collection of Resources for Learning English is worth highlighting, as well as [StoneyB's awesome Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/)*

Comment: We haven't seen StoneyB for a while, but he was the guvnor, as they say. And he was gracious enough to christen and link to [FumbleFingers‘ **Perfect** Truism](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/126) in his (truly awesome) Canonical post.

Comment: The usage chart would be more interesting, in my opinion, if you had included "sweater was knitted" and "sweater was knit".  I suspect that the difference in knit/knitted frequency between "she knit/knitted me ..." and "bones knit/knitted" might have more to do with what is being knitted (clothing vs bones) than whether you're looking at a participle or a simple past.  I also do believe that there's a US/UK distinction afoot here.  I am not American, and I would always use "knitted".  To me, "she knit" as a past tense feels just as foreign as "she spit" as the past tense.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: I'm already pushing NGrams to the limit with the my 3-4 word search strings. There aren't enough matches to drill down into US/UK corpuses separately, or to add an extra word to the search strings.

Comment: ...BELAY THAT! I just ran off [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sweater+was+knit%2Csweater+was+knitted&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) comparing "sweater was knitted" and "sweater was knit" as you suggested. There aren't enough hits to chart just the UK corpus, but I realised I *can* meaningfully compare "ALL English" with ["US English"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sweater+was+knit%2Csweater+was+knitted&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10)...

Comment: ...where obviously the difference between the ALL link and the US link above is basically the UK corpus anyway. If you look at those two charts, you'll see that in the US-only version, ***sweater was knit*** has overtaken ***sweater was knitted*** in the last two decades. This *hasn't* happened in the ALL corpus - presumably because there's a marked preference in BrE for the regular form ***knitted***, which is just enough to shift the usage trend. In short, against all expectations, it seems ***was knit*** is *gaining*, not *losing* traction - and this is primarily driven by AmE, not BrE.

Comment: An additional point in favour of using _knit_ as a past participle: a community may be **tight-knit** or **close-knit**, but unless we’re in a parallel universe where shawls and sweaters form communities, I’ve personally never come across a *tight-knitted or *close-knitted community.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That point was also raised by [@MichaelHarvey](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332092/i-was-knit-a-sweater/332102?noredirect=1#comment628518_332095). I didn't take it any further because by the time I read that I was already thinking that whereas *my* perspective here (that Collins made a mistake) was "interesting" (to the likes of me, you, and Michael), it wasn't necessarily helpful for most *learners*.

Comment: ...Anyway, since I know you're a dab hand at "etymological research", is there any chance you can look into whether this is an example of ***irregular verb gaining traction**?* Ever since I read Pinker's book about irregular verbs many years ago, I've assumed they're (nearly?) always dying out, not coming to life. I'd quite like to see this one kicked around a bit on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In OE, it was a weak verb ([class I, subclass III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_weak_verb#Class_I,_subclass_(iii))), which means it had the regular, weak _-de_ ending in the past tense, but because the stem ends in /t/, that was assimilated into _-te_, so the past and present forms were largely identical: 1sg _cnytte_. The participle ended regularly in _-ed_, though: _(ġe)cnytted_. Already in ME, these start getting mixed up, with both past _knytted_ from the participle and participle _(y)knyt_ from the past appearing, and this has continued to the present.

Comment: The same applies to **fit**. I find it odd when Americans write something like "I tried the jeans on and they fit me", where I would use _fitted_ for the past tense.

Comment: @KateBunting: Perhaps I should have used an example like *He **kitted** the team out in the new strip yesterday*, rather than ***...fitted** the cat-clap.*

Answer (score 9):

Your sentence is perfect, and means exactly what you intended it to mean.

It sounds even more acceptable to me than "I was knitted a sweater" (which other posters are suggesting you to use based on what Collins dictionary says about knit's conjugations).

When I read the title before opening your question, I understood that it means *Someone knit a sweater for me*. I thought an English learner had read this sentence somewhere and was asking about how to understand this passive construction, which is extra confusing as far as passives go because the verb has irregular conjugations and variable transitivity. But actually you created it - awesome!

Most people seem to find *knitted* more acceptable though, rather than *knit*, so you may want to change it. I was surprised by the Collins dictionary entry and the top answer and comments here, I didn't know I'm apparently in a small minority for never inflecting *knit*.

[image]

[image]

Apparently the past tense form of this verb is sexist.

Comment: It also seems to depend on what you knit! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+knit+her+brows%2Cshe+knitted+her+brows%2C+he+knit+his+brows%2C+he+knitted+his+brows&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 9):

**No, you shouldn’t say this.**  Some native speakers might say it, but most would find it awkward, and it’s a bit nonstandard.

There are two independent issues here:

- should the past participle be *knit* or *knitted?*
- can you use the structure *I was given a sweater* (the “ditransitive passive”) with *knit[ted]*?

Other answers treat the first question well: **the [traditional standard](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/332095/851) past participle in most contexts is *knitted*, but *knit* is [also common](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/332102/851)**, so I wouldn’t call it wrong.

However **the ditransitive passive form doesn’t work with *knit***.  Your example *I was given a sweater* is fine; but this form works better with some verbs than others.  Verbs like this that can take two direct objects (as in *Sue gave me a sweater*, *Sue knit me a sweater*) are called *ditransitive*, and they generally fall into two classes according whether the first object can be rephrased with *to* (like *Sue gave a sweater to me*) or with *for* (like *Sue knitted a sweater for me*).  **The passive form *Tom was VERBed a NOUN* is generally standard with *to*-type ditransitives, but not with *for*-type ditransitives.**  So you can say *I was given a cake*, *I was sent flowers*, *I was offered a loan*, but NOT *I was baked a cake*, *I was ordered flowers*, *I was arranged a loan*.  And as [Peter Kirkpatrick’s answer notes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/332095/851), ditransitive *knit* is a *for*-type, not a *to*-type.

Passives of *for*-type ditransitives aren’t completely wrong — they do occur in native speaker usage — but they are rare, and usually feel awkward.  Going to a very authoritative reference, Huddleston and Pullum (*Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, 2002, Ch.4 §4.3 Ditransitive clauses) write “many speakers find [examples like *I was ordered a book*] marginally possible”.

Comment: The perfect answer -- it even explains why I (a native speaker) was uncertain about the validity of the OP's sentence.

Comment: Huh, never thought about the difference between _to_- and _for_-type transitives here. Even with the _for_ type, though, it seems to me there are differences – for example, I find “I was knit(ted) a sweater” and “I was baked a cake” completely unremarkable, but “I was ordered flowers” is a bit odd, and “I was arranged a loan” is completely impossible to me, and I had to do a fair bit of mental gymnastics to even get the meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Agreed about the variation between verbs, though my intuition for the specific examples is different from yours — for me “knitted” and “baked” are no better than “ordered”.  The cited section in CGEL also notes this, saying “Ditransitive verbs vary considerable in how readily they occur in passive clauses”, and discusses some more subtleties about what can affect the acceptability of different cases — but they present the *to-/for-* division as the main factor, and that fits my intuition + experience well.

Comment: What about "I was made a cake." That seems fine to me.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I think it really depends on speaker. I find "arranged a loan" impossible, "baked a cake" and "knit a sweater not great  but not problematic and "ordered flowers" unexceptionable. And "made a cake" is worse for me than "baked a cake". Looking at usage data would probably be necessary and chances are there would be regional variations. The knit/vs. knitted graphs are quite interesting in another answer here.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the verb to knit can be used in a passive sense. However we need to tidy up your grammar, which is not correct.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/knit#:%7E:text=Word%20forms%3A%203rd%20person%20singular,for%20meaning%20%5Bsense%204%5D.) gives these words as the tenses of knit:

- knits (present tense)
- knitting (present participle)
- knitted (past tense and past participle)

Collins does list one example where the past tense can be 'knit' or knitted', but this is the technical sense of broken bones knitting back together.

So for your basic example (assuming we are talking about knitting done in the past) we would say, "Someone knitted a sweater."

Also, we would say "knitted a sweater **for** me" (not to me). If you're not sure why, search for articles on indirect objects in a sentence.

So the full sentence becomes "Someone knitted a sweater for me." Then we can change the form of the sentence from active to passive like this:

- "The sweater was knitted (by X) for me."

You can also say:

- "I was knitted a sweater."

...which has the same grammar as "I was given a sweater." It means that I was the one for whom the sweater was knitted.

Comment: I don't like to disagree with Collins, but I'm fine with ***knit*** as both past tense *(Nan knit me a sweater last year)* and past participle *(She has knit me a sweater every year)*. I haven't gone looking, but I'm quite sure I could find plenty of examples to support my position heree.

Comment: Sweater of ages, knit for me, let me warm myself in thee!

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a Southern English RP speaker, born among Cockneys, I would find 'a sweater knit for me' a little stilted and old-fashioned, although I am OK with e.g. 'a close-knit (or tight-knit) family'.

Comment: Collins: LANGUAGE NOTE:  
The past tense can be either knit or knitted for meaning [sense 4]. This answer does not deserve a dv.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Absolutely! *My nan knit me this sweater* is "a little stilted and old-fashioned" to me too. But Collins is *way* out of line not even recognizing that the usage exists (and I certainly wouldn't call it "archaic" or "obsolete", so there's no excuse on that front).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - off-topic, I know, and maybe I'm revealing a disagreeable side of myself, but I do get all riled up when I see in newspapers stuff like 'Nan aged 80 in car crash', 'Mary Smith, the mum of three boys, was charged with shoplifting', etc. What happened to 'grandmother', 'mother', etc?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: The one that got on my tits a few days ago (Guardian or BBC, I don't recall) was ***Father of one** shot dead*. I've always understood ***Mother / Father of N*** as a kind of "sympathy-grabbing" device to make us think about all those ***N*** children who lost a parent. But when ***N=1*** it kinda "cheapens" it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was taken aback as a boy to read of a 'mother of nine' in my old man's Daily Express.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: My old man was a father of five (who had *twelve* siblings, making Grandpa a father of *thirteen*, though I never met him), so I wouldn't have seen anything particularly odd about *nine*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I meant I read 'a mother of nine' like 'a boy of nine'.

Comment: Ooops! I didn't even see that parsing!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - my dear Mama said that while girls of nine had been known to give birth, the figure was much more likely to refer to the number of offspring.

Comment: Returning to the actual subject here.... it occurs to me that if we had a migration route for sending questions from ELL to ELU I would *definitely* vote for that here. On the KISS principle, learners would probably be better off believing Collins, and treating ***to knit*** as a regular verb. But even though you say you find the irregular past forms stilted / old-fashioned, that's a *long* way from saying they're "invalid". I can see I won't get much support for my position here, but at least on ELU I think I'd get more help putting the boot in on that Collins "howler"! :)

Comment: I just made a "non-edit" to your answer so I could reverse my downvote (which was really a fit of pique aimed at Collins; I can't argue with the wisdom of *learners* following your advice!  :)