# I was *cooked/fried/roasted/boiled* onions

Tags: passive-voice

Can the following verbs be used in this passive-voice structure? The meaning I want this sentence to have is *Onions were cooked/fried/roasted/boiled for me*.

1. I was cooked/fried/roasted/boiled onions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was knit a sweater](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332092/i-was-knit-a-sweater)

Answer (score 1):

All of those sound odd to me, with the possible exception of "cooked".

They're all acceptable in the active ditransitive construction:

> He cooked/fried/roasted/boiled me some onions.

but not in the passive.

I think it is partly because of the lack of determiner. In my example above, I wrote "some onions" without even thinking about it, and was surprised not to find "some" in your question.

If you add *some*, I find your examples a bit more acceptable:

> I was cooked/fried/roasted/boiled some onions.

which leads me to think that one reason for my discomfort with your examples was the alternative reading: "I was fried onions" where "fried" is an adjective. Semantically unlikely, but syntactically simpler.

But they're still pretty marginal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its tricky to understand what you need to know but all of these verbs can be used in passive form.
You say 'I was'...Do you mean to say,
'I was cooking onions? ' ACTIVE

The onions were being cooked or even, the onions were cooked. (PASSIVE)
The onions were cooked/fried/roasted/boiled...is correct in passive tense too.
Does this help?