# Past Perfect & Past Simple + Before

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

As we can see in
https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html

> If the past perfect is not referring to an action at a specific time, past perfect is not optional. Compare the examples below. Here past perfect is referring to a lack of experience rather than an action at a specific time. For this reason, simple past cannot be used.
>
> She never saw a bear before she moved to Alaska. Not Correct
>
> She had never seen a bear before she moved to Alaska. Correct

But I found the next sentences in the textbooks:

I never was in such a difficult situation before.

And

Before I went to the university, I worked as a carpenter for 5 years

So, is the quotation in the beginning wrong? And may we write "She never saw a bear before she moved to Alaska." by analogy with "I never was in such a difficult situation before ?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["She never saw a bear before she moved to Alaska." Why incorrect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/she-never-saw-a-bear-before-she-moved-to-alaska-why-incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the  traditional grammarians, when  two actions  happened  in the  past , the  first  action  should  be  in  the  past  perfect  and  the  second  action  should  be  in  the  simple  past:

So  the  correct  sentences  should be:

> **She had  never  seen a  bear before  she moved to  Alaska**

But  descriptive grammarians  like  Michael Swan  say  that  the  conjunctions before  and  after  refer  to   the sequence  of  the  actions  and  that  past  perfect  is optional.

So  *she never  saw  a  bear  before  she  moved  toAlaska*

is  also  correct.

Similarly, *Before  I went  to  the university, I  worked  as  a  carpenter  for  5  years*   is  equally  correct.

Besides, I worked  as  a  carpenter  for 5 years  seems to be  a  past  habit. so  past  perfect  is  not  necessary  anyway.

Even  the adverb  never can  be  used  in  the  simple past  and  the  past  perfect.

So  sentences  such  as:

*I  never  saw  such  an  inciden  before* is  equally  correct  as  *i  had  never seen  such  an  incident  before/ earlier*

Here  is  a link  which  helps  you.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/before