# Difference between Simple Past and Past Perfect

Tags: past-perfect, perfect-constructions, backshifting

What is the difference in meaning between the two examples below?

> 1. When she returned home from office, she was shocked to see that her husband and daughter **were** missing. (Simple Past)
> 2. When she returned home from office, she was shocked to see that her husband and daughter **had been** missing. (Past Perfect)

FIRST QUESTION: For me example #1 gives only idea of Status of her missing husband and daughter and example #2 gives idea of completed action/situation of missing husband and daughter before she reached home. Is this right?

SECOND QUESTION: Is example #2 ***past perfect*** or ***past perfect continuous***?

Comment: @MaulikV Actually, people aren't supposed to make edits that [invalidate existing answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=invalidate%20existing%20answers) in the first place...

Comment: @F.E. The question first asked 'past perfect' in a broader way. After the edit, it asked (which it should have earlier), the past perfect continuous. The difference between 'simple past' and 'past perfect **continuous**' is what I felt should have mentioned earlier. And, I did not know that you edited it. If you have and **not** OP, then my comment is invalid! :) If you see, I did not addressed you in the comment, I thought OP changed his mind. I thought you might have fixed some grammar. Said that, I'm now deleting my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that your Sentence 1 expresses a complete thought.

But your Sentence 2 is incomplete (expresses an incomplete thought). For Sentence 2 to be complete, you need to specify some *time in the past* that is previous to the time that the subject *she* returned home. For example:

Sentence 3

> When she returned home from the office, she was shocked to see that her husband and daughter had been missing **since noon** or **since Tuesday** or **for an hour** or **for a month**.

All four of these *past times* are previous to the time the subject *she* returned home.

Unless you specify some *past time*, the sentence is incomplete in thought.

And yes, *had been missing* is past perfect continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Your assumption is correct!

Answer 2: It's past perfect continuous.

To use *past perfect continuous*, try to understand *past prefect* first.

We use past perfect to show that the event occurred *before* something happened in the past. Here, they went missing, but if you want to show that 'missing' happened *before* her coming (which is also in the past), we use exactly the way you have quoted the sentence. We may call it as an 'early past'.

> When she returned home.... her husband and daughter had been missing.

I'm pasting a useful portion from the [British Council page for learning English.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/past-perfect)

Let's see two sentences

> - John left the house at 7:30 yesterday morning.
> - Mary rang John’s doorbell at 8:15 yesterday.

Both actions happened in the past, so we use the past simple tense. But look at how we can combine the sentences:

> Mary rang John’s doorbell at 8:15 yesterday, but John had already left the house.

We use the past perfect (had left) **because the action happened before another action in the past** (Mary rang the doorbell).

Look at some more examples of the past perfect:

> - When Mrs Brown opened the washing machine, she realised she had washed the cat.
> - I got a letter from Jim last week. We’d been at school together, but we’d lost touch with each other.

The past perfect is used because they were at school **before he received the letter. It refers to an earlier past.**

Past perfect continuous just adds '-ing' verb to the past perfect. [More on this topic here.](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/past_perfect_continuous)