# Would it be idiomatic to use past perfect in "I forgot I (had) promised"?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, backshifting

The following is from a movie on YouTube called "Daughter Kidnapped" ([a link to that moment](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BkqB5pyu7N8&pp=ygUTRGF1Z2h0ZXIga2lkbmFwcGVkIA%3D%3D&t=30m11s)):

Ally is Paige's Daughter. Ally's father has died recently. Diane is the owner of a farm in the woods that she's made into a rehabilitation facility for people like Ally and Paige so they can recover there after their loss. Ally and Paige checked in there just a couple of days ago. They're now settling in. Paige comes up to Diane, tells her that she and her daughter like it there, then she falls silent, but doesn't leave, so Diane continues the conversation:

*Diane: "Is there something else?"*

*Paige: "Yes, actually, I forgot I **promised** Ally I'd ask about us getting out of here on some errands, maybe grab some mother-daughter time."*

*Diane: "I'm sorry, Paige. I thought we **discussed** this. There's no leaving the compound during the initial three month commitment."*

Would the dialog be idiomatic if the past perfect was used for the bolded verbs there: "*...I forgot I'**d promised** Ally I'd ask...*" and "*...I thought we'**d discussed** this...*"? Is the use of the past perfect correct in this context?

Comment: Most of the **time**, it depends on what **you want to say** and not grammar. The past perfect **always** means something precedes it. "had discussed it** **precedes I thought**. It's most often a question of emphasis. Of course, there are some situations (court cases or litigation) where the difference might be crucial. "Did the dog bark after the killer had entered the house or not?"Yes, it would be idiomatic, to answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Simple Past and Past Perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56103/difference-between-simple-past-and-past-perfect)