# After I had done, they did vs After I did, they did

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, tense-agreement

Which is correct? or are both correct? or are they both grammatically correct but only different in semantics?

1. > After Sally **had mastered** the skills for her job, her supervisor **asked** her to help train new employees.
2. > After Sally **mastered** the skills for her job, her supervisor **asked** her to help train new employees.

Comment: Related: **[When is the past perfect exactly needed?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)**

Comment: Another one: **[What is the Perfect, and how should I use it?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)**

Answer (score 4):

Either is fine, although the second is more concise, and at least equally clear, so I'd pick that one.

The past perfect (1st sentence) would be preferable when the events are out of order:

- Sally's supervisor asked her to train new employees after she had mastered the skills for her job.