# The importance of using "Had"

Tags: word-usage

"By the time i got my hands on the phone, the phone **had** stopped ringing."

""By the time i got my hands on the phone, the phone stopped ringing."

In similar contexts, and in the sentences above, how important is the usage of **had** ?
Is it okay to not use it, and just go for using the simple past instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple past and the past perfect imply slightly different things.  In this case, I would definitely use the past perfect with **had**.  The simple past just states that something happened in the past, with no specific implications about when:

> The mailman left.
>   The prime minister resigned.
>   The ship sailed away.

The past perfect is used to indicate that something happened before another specific event in the past.  We use it to relate two past events, like:

> I rushed to the door, but the mailman had already left. (that is, before I got to the door)
>   They told me that the prime minister had resigned. (*had resigned*, because the resignation was before they told me)
>   The ship had sailed away by the time the police arrived.  (the ship sailed, then later the police arrived)

Sometimes it doesn't make a great difference.  For example, it would be normal and unremarkable to say "The phone stopped ringing before I could get to it" or even "Before I could get to it, the phone stopped ringing."  But putting *by the time* in there makes it look like a specific comparison of times, so the past perfect feels more natural.

References:
[PAST PERFECT](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/)

[When is the past perfect exactly needed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)

[Past perfect and simple past compared](http://www.monash.edu.au/lls/llonline/grammar/tense/3.3.xml)