# What's the difference between "I didn't sing the song" and "I had not sung the song"?

Tags: tense, past-perfect, past-simple

I wanted to ask that what is the difference between the following sentences:

> "I didn't sing the song."
>   "I had not sung the song."

Comment: You would probably find our sister site *English Language Learners* more helpful for this type of question.

Comment: The first says that at some point in the past when the opportunity to sing arose you chose not to sing- it's about your choices at the point of singing.  The second is about what happened in your life *up to* that point of opportunity. Prior to that point you never sang [had never sung] the song before. The sentence may imply that you did sing at that point. But doesn't require it:  "When they asked me if I had ever sung the song before, I told them I had not sung it, and never will."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, the meanings are very similar, for the difference is context.

I didn't sing the song - This is a sentence that can stand alone, in response to a question or as a statement of fact.

I had not sung the song - This phrasing would typically be used in context of another event, or as part of an explanation to a series of events. On it's own this sentence would seem strange.

i.e. "Until I knew the tune, I had not sung the song"

Answer (score 1):

They both grammatical

The difference is

> I didn't sing the song

Is simple past tense and

> I hadn't sung the song

Is past perfect tense

We use past simple when the action started in the past and completed in the past. Past perfect is also used for a completed action in the past but the action was not interupted by any action before another action.

For example : I had eaten some food before I went to bed last night.

*Had eaten..* was completed before *went to bed* and it was not interupted by  any action

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence is in pluperfect tense: it speaks of an event in relation to some later event, which is also in the speaker's past.

- We expected Harry to sing “Six String Orchestra”, but at intermission he still *had not sung it*.  (Maybe he sang it later.)

The first form does not imply such a reference point.

- I went to Harry's concert and was disappointed that he *did not sing* my favorite song.

This also refers to a time, but to a *range* of time as a whole rather than *before* a specific point.