# Confusion with the verb tense used in the dependent clause

Tags: tense, subordinate-clauses

> I had put my glasses on the table, and my friend forgot to take it for me when we *went* outside.

First, I **had put** my glasses, and then my friend **forgot**. That is why I use Past Perfect for the first clause and Past Simple for the second one.

However, I do not understand the situation with the dependent clause. Please, help me to understand which verb tense I need to use in the dependent clause.

Comment: Past perfect is frequently avoided, many people would say "I put my glasses on the table, ..."

Comment: *Glasses* takes the plural pronoun *them*, whether the word *glasses* refers to the kind you wear to improve your eyesight or the glass containers you drink liquids out of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)