# Does the past perfect tense make sense in this sentence? "Sent from an "is" to a "was" before he'd had his breakfast."

Tags: tense, past-tense, sequence-of-tenses

From the movie Lucky Number Slevin:

> (He was) Relegated to the past tense. (He was) Sent from an "is" to a "was" before **he'd had** his breakfast.

The context is Morgan Freeman's character is telling another person how his son was killed in the morning, before breakfast. The use of past perfect tense here doesn't make sense to me, because it contradicts what the past perfect tense is used for. (e.g. [When is the past perfect exactly needed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)) Either "before he had his breakfast" or "before he would have his breakfast" seem better options. Does the past perfect tense read fine to you? Why?

Answer (score 6):

A state of completion can be fixed in time by the perfect tenses.

> He had eaten his breakfast by 9AM.

In other words, breakfast was *finished* by 9AM.

To "have" breakfast is to eat it, **not** *to have eaten it*.

"Do you want to have breakfast?" is an invitation to eat, not a question about whether you wish you had already eaten.

If you *do* want to use the verb tense to mean "finished breakfast", we need the past participle of lexical verb "have", which is "had":

> I have<sup>aux</sup> had<sup>lex</sup> breakfast already today. No more for me, thanks.
>
> I had<sup>aux</sup> had<sup>lex</sup> breakfast already when she offered me some yesterday. I told
>   her, no thanks.

Thus, the phrase *before he **had had** his breakfast* refers to a time in the past prior to its having been finished. He was killed before he had finished breakfast.

Comment: Well, yeah that's something I am very familiar with. I even link to a detailed usage explanation on this site. I asked my question _because_ I know all this, and the sentence doesn't accord to all this. So it's really a question about the sentence specifically.

Comment: But the sentence does accord to all of this.

Comment: He wasn't killed "before breakfast". He was killed before he had had breakfast.

Comment: It actually should be, "He **had been killed** *before* he **had** breakfast", but that's very formal, fancy English.  The reason is that his death occurs first; then breakfast follows.

Comment: That is not the only way the past perfect is used, Nicholas.  This is perfectly valid: *Before he had even gotten in the door the kids started asking about pizza.*  The asking about pizza occurs before he got inside, but we don't have to make that asking the "earlier" of the two events:  *Before he got inside, the kids had started asking about pizza*

Answer (score 5):

**Michael Swan**  comments on this issue in ***Practical English Usage***:

In clauses with **before**, we often use present perfect and past
perfect tenses to emphasise the idea of completion.
*You can't go home before I've signed the letters.* (= ...
before the moment when I have completed the letters.)
*He went out before I had finished my sentence.* (= ...
before the moment when I had completed my sentence.)
(**Note that in sentences like the last, a past perfect tense can
refer to a time later than the action of the main verb. This is
unusual.**)

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola Please don't post your point of view in the comments section under the question *and* every single answer, and then post a comment complaining about downvotes on your own answer.  If you want to present your point of view, you can do so *in your own answer*, which you have done.  There is no need to put it everywhere else as well.  This is a question-and-answer site, not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

With Respect to Nicholas I agree with TRomano and Mv Log based on reference to Michael Swan.

CGEL, Michael Swan, and Hornby all state that we can use either the Past Simple or the Past Perfect after the conjuction "**before**".

In order to make it clearer I will swap "**had**" for "**started eating**".

So all four variants will be correct:

1. He **was sent** from an "is" to a "was" before **he had started eating** his breakfast.
2. He **was sent** from an "is" to a "was" before **he started eating** his breakfast.
3. He **had been sent** from an "is" to a "was" before **he started eating** his breakfast.
4. He **had been sent** from an "is" to a "was" before **he had started eating** his breakfast.

The main idea is that he hadn't even started eating before he was killed. "**had had**" may either mean "**had started**" or "**had finished**" and this may be a bit of a confusion to most readers. I know I've had it before I had found out about it and learned to tell the difference.

> "**Practical English Usage**" by Michael Swan. Page #84.
>
> - He **went out** before I **had finished** my sentence.
>
> A **Past Perfect** tense can refer to a time *later* than the action of the main verb.

Here follows:

> A special way to use "**before**" preceding the *Past Perfect* in reference to an action appearing later: *one that was not completed* or *that didn't yet start*.

Here's the printed quote from Michael Swan:

[image]

Here's a quote from [English Grammar Online](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpas-pasper):

[image]

Here's a quote from Applied English Grammar and Composition by Dr Sharma M.M.:

[image]

Comment: It suffices to google "before he had had" which returns some 2.5m articles:  _They dismissed him before he had had a chance to apologize. She sacked him before he had had a chance to explain his behaviour._ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Since dead people don't generally eat,

> ... before he could have breakfast

or

> ... before he could break his fast

would be correct. Morgan and Nick both err.

To clarify, the sentence as written is perfectly reasonable *grammar*, but it's illogical in the circumstances.

Answer (score -5):

I disagree with everyone's answer thus far.  It should be,

> "before he **had** breakfast." (past simple)

*See* https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/time-conjunctions-perfect-tense/

http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/the-past-perfect-simple-tense/

Normally, the past perfect precedes the conjunction *before* and follows the conjunction *after*:

> "I **had run** a mile *before* I **ate** breakfast."
>
> "I **ate** breakfast *after* I **had run** a mile."

In the example given above, "He *was killed* **before** he *had had* breakfast" is incorrect English; it should read:

> "He **had been** killed *before* he **had** breakfast."

The reason for this is that his death occurs prior to his eating breakfast.  The past perfect is used to tell the listener or reader which event or events in the past occurred first:

> "I **had answered** the question *before* the teacher **asked** it."
>
> "The teacher **asked** the question *after* I **had** (already)
>   **answered** it."
>
> "I **mowed** the grass *after* I **had eaten** lunch.
>
> "I **had eaten** lunch *before* I **mowed** the grass.

Now compare the last example above to the following sentence:

> "I **ate** lunch *after* I **had mown** the grass."

In this example, my eating lunch follows in time in the past my mowing the grass.  In the original example, the actions are flip-flopped.

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.

**P.S..** *The examples given by others in which the past perfect follows the conjunction "before" and the past simple precedes the same conjunction is often heard in spoken English, but it is merely a common error in speech.  In other words, it's incorrect English, but it's pretty prevalent.  Like the subjunctive mood, this is another pet peeve of mine regarding how native speakers use the language.*

Comment: Do you have any evidence for the assertion in your postscript? Neither link addresses this case (and the terminology "Past Perfect Simple Tense" is a mouthful and contradictory). The argument seems to rely on a too strict reading of a few grammar rules coupled with a prescriptivist viewpoint

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola I don't understand why so many downvoted your answer either. Also can you elaborate on the point you made about the subjunctive mood in spoken English?

Comment: They downvoted it because they don't know what they're talking about and I pointed it out; so, as not to look bad, they tried to make me look like a fool. I showed them all the evidence they wanted to see and still they kept asking me to show them evidence as if they were "Flat Earthers"--people who still think the Earth is flat. As for the subjunctive, what do you want to know? Ask a question on this forum about it and I shall answer it. I just said that the subjunctive is a common error like the one above.

Comment: @NicholasCastagnola I am just curious why you said the subjunctive is a common error. What do you mean it is an error? Also, upvoted.

Comment: I said that, "Like the subjunctive mood, this past perfect usage with the conjunction *before* is a common error in spoken English." In other words, native speakers make mistakes with the past perfect with the conjunction *before* just as much as they fail to use or misuse the subjunctive mood in spoken English. I'm not saying the subjunctive mood is an error; I'm saying that they often skip the subjunctive mood and, instead, use the indicative when it is not correct. Sometimes they even use the subjunctive mood when it should be the indicative. Just a common error.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I know using the indicative when the subjunctive should be used is a common practice, but I can't think of an example of the opposite. Can you give me an example of a common error where the subjunctive is used in place of the indicative?

Comment: "I asked him if my answer *were* correct" is an example of using the subjunctive when it should be the indicative. It should be, "I asked if (or whether) my answer *was* correct." This is an example of a hypercorrection. It is not correct as there is no subjunctive clause here. Also, would you upvote my new answer above? Someone downvoted the correct answer again.

Comment: Nick, I think you are misreading it. You must have had a rough day whereupon you've earned yourself a foggy mind. Your examples are indeed correct but that isn't the structure of the OP's sentence. I am not a native speaker but even I see it clearly. Take your "**mowing**" example and you get "*I ate lunch before I had started mowing the grass*". Likewise we have "*I woke him up before I had had my tea*" - which means you first woke him up and then either went to make yourself tea or went to finish it *(finish drinking)*.