# Is it better to use simple past or present perfect for a future event?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple, future-time

> If any man hurts my daughter, I will hurt him as much as he **has hurt** her

Could it be past simple as at the time of writing the hurting if there was one,  it would  be finished and hopefully would not happen again . But what bother me is that all verbs in this sentence relate to present or future so may be present perfect is a better choice

> If any man hurts my daughter, I will hurt him as much as he hurt her

Answer (score -3):

Your own suggestion sounds good to me:

> If any man hurts my daughter, I will hurt him as much as he hurt her.

It seems grammatically correct, and flows well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93138)

Comment: In what way does it not answer the question?  They asked which was better, and I said which was better?  Please advise what would be a better answer.  Just shooting it down without giving any explanation or providing an improvement isn't very helpful to people starting out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. SE strives to provide *definitive* answers, and as such, a response is not an answer unless it provides an explanation of the *why*, not just the *what*, with appropriate explanation, examples, and references. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. For a couple of well-regarded answers on the past perfect consider those provided for *[When is the past perfect exactly needed?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/)*.