# What's the difference between Past Simple and Past Participle?

Tags: grammar

**Past Perfect** is one of the English past tenses, used to indicate that one of 2 past actions took place before another, like in the sentence:

- I had written my homework before I went for a walk.

**Past Participle** is one of the verb forms (usually the third form in a table of irregular verbs).

What's the difference?

Comment: The past participle (written) is used in the formation of the past perfect tense (I had written).

Comment: Your title is about "past participles" but your question appears to be about "past perfect". Are you confusing the terms? If so, your question is a duplicate of [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/when-is-the-past-perfect-exactly-needed)

Answer (score 1):

Despite its name, the past participle is a non-finite verb form, which means that it has no tense.  The past participle is used:

- in forming the present perfect ("I have written")
- in forming the past perfect ("I had written")
- in forming the perfect infinitive ("(to) have written", as in "I must have written")
- in forming passives ("it was written")
- attributively as a descriptor ("a quickly written poem").

In many cases, the simple past is identical in form to the past participle ("I *said*", "I have *said*").  In other cases, they are different ("I *did*", "I have *done*").

Once you know what the past participle is, you can combine it with forms of "have" to form the present perfect and past perfect - hence there is no need for a table of irregular verb forms to include the past perfect: it just needs to include the past participle.