# past perfect to continue a flash back

Tags: past-perfect

> Not knowing anything about this mystery record and band other than what label it was on, I went straight to the source for some information. I asked Robbie Fields, the Posh Boy, what the story was with it and he was quite happy to share the story with me for this feature.
>
> 391 was an essential part of the learning curve for the new Posh Boy label.
>
> The background: **I had been** a huge fan of The Nuns in 1977. In fact, the Nuns were arguably the first “punk” group I saw, headlining the Whiskey with The Dickies in late ’77. This was the Alejandro Escovedo era Nuns that played as a group, with three lead singers. I had hung out with singer Jeff Olener at the Masque after that first Whiskey show and become friendly, albeit in a fan worship kind of way.
>
> Later, I **had seen** Jeff after they opened for The Sex Pistols at Winterland in San Francisco. The band that I managed, F Word!, were lucky to be the opening act several times for The Nuns at S.F.’s Mabuhay Gardens.

I understand the first past perfect I **had been** a huge fan it is a flash back, does it work the same way for **had seen** to indicate I am still continuing the flash back, was it necessary to use past perfect.  But "Later, I had seen after they opened..." seems strange

<sub>http://www.punkvinyl.com/2005/10/10/selections-from-the-punk-vault-391/ is the reference</sub>

Comment: Although you didn't explicitly highlight it, there's also *I **had** hung out* in the middle of your first cited paragraph. Personally I think it's at the very least *unnecessary* to continue with past perfect once the "past within the past" context has been established by the first usage. And in the cited context, it seems inherently *clumsy*, since there's no obvious logical principle to explain why the writer *didn't* use it for many other verbs *(the Nuns **had been** ... I **had seen** ... this **had been** .. **had become** etc.)*

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is using the past perfect tense not necessary?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/when-is-using-the-past-perfect-tense-not-necessary)

Comment: @FumbleFingers *become* **is** a past perfect. I offer an explanation for the actual pasts below.

Comment: @StoneyB: Oops! - I was on a different (smaller) screen earlier, and read it as ***became***. I see now that it *is* past perfect (albeit with an elipted ***had*** carried over from ***had hung out***). I understand the point as made in your answer that PP is indeed used "judiciously" (so I must retreat from my earlier "no obvious principle"), but I still think that as a more useful general principle, it's often unnecessary and potentially distracting/clumsy to use PP repeatedly in text spanning multiple paragraphs (by then it practically becomes its *own* "reference time").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields, who is the speaker for everything except the first passage you quote, deploys his past perfects very consistently to refer to states arising out of  eventualities which occurred before his "reference time", the time at which *391* became "an essential part of the learning curve". This is identified (with a simple past) in the next paragraph:

> So it must have been sometime in 1979 that I **was** contacted out of the blue by Jeff Olener.

Note that Fields reverts to the past perfect in later passages, where he is once more referring reference-time states arising out of prior eventualities:

> . . . nothing **had** seen the light of day. The first fashion directed wave of punk **had** been and crashed. Even my Beach Blvd album seemed to **have** spent itself very quickly over its first summer of 1979.
>
> Jeff Olener **had** put together a rock band. ... *and more*
>
> Up to this point, I had had very little studio experience. We had recorded the Beach Blvd. album at Media Art in Hermosa Beach.

In fact, the only place Fields does not employ the past perfect for these anterior eventualities is in the passage FumbleFingers calls out:

> In fact, the Nuns **were** arguably the first “punk” group I saw, headlining the Whiskey with The Dickies in late ’77. This **was** the Alejandro Escovedo era Nuns that played as a group, with three lead singers.

The unbolded pasts are in subordinate relatives, hence beyond the scope of the perfect; and I take the bolded main-clause pasts to mark a [tense-shifted](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13262/32) parenthetical.

All in all, I think Fields' story is a model for judicious use of the past perfect in narrative.

Comment: I think as Fumblefingers think:  why so many past perfect, only one in the first paragraph at the beginning may be one in the second also at the beginning.So many past perfect make me believe that the reference time is past perfect not past simple

Comment: @user5577 1) The eventuality expressed in a perfect cannot be at reference time, only the state arising out of that eventuality. 2) There are three perfects in Fields' second paragraph: *had seen*, *had hung, *[had] become*. 3) All of these perfects express states obtaining at reference time (narrative time), when Olener contacted Fields. 4) The simple pasts in those passages are either parenthetical commentary or appear in subordinate clauses whose time reference lies in the 'temporal field' of the perfect anterior eventuality, not in that of the reference time.