# Had sent/ sent... which one's better, and why?

Tags: tense, past-participles

I was overwhelmed with joy when i read the texts you **had** sent me.

I was overwhelmed with joy when i read the texts you sent me.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: A great resource about perfect: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it

Comment: The second one shows a chain of actions that happened right one after another. When the meaning is clear, you don't need past perfect.

Comment: This might be useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/when-is-using-the-past-perfect-tense-not-necessary

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences mean the same thing, that someone sent you texts which made you happy.

Using **had sent** (past perfect), shows that the sender finished sending before the next action: that you were **overwhelmed**. However, in this case, there is no ambiguity in the **order of actions** since you could only become overwhelmed **after** the texts were sent.

For my experience, the second sentence is used more, the first sounds too **learned**.

Comment: Does it sound less learned to you if the person says "... you'd sent me"?