# present perfect in this case because the time indicated is not finished

Tags: present-perfect

We **have just discovered**  today after the workers left ,that  there is a water leak, some   water  is falling from the ceiling in the kitchen. As the workers  had already left we could not speak to them and  ask  them what was happening. We  **have put** two  buckets  found  near the washing machine.

I used present perfect for discover because  when I discovered the leak the day was not finished yet  . Can I  also use  present perfect for put because both actions are quite simultaneus and still in the present 
or should I have used past simple for discovered and present perfect for have put I don't think so because of today.

Comment: You *could* use Past Perfect for both verbs, but why not just use Simple Past? It means exactly the same, uses less words, and it's *easier*.

Comment: past perfect no present perfect

Comment: Well, it's too late for me to edit the comment. Anyway, it's still an "unnecessary" use of the perfect verb form. Here's another one: [When is using the past perfect tense not necessary?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/when-is-using-the-past-perfect-tense-not-necessary). The bottom line is lots of learners seem to be keen to use perfect forms just because they might be "not wrong" even where most native speakers simply wouldn't bother.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is an interesting phenomenon (" lots of learners seem to be keen to use perfect forms") and one that I never encountered until I stumbled upon ELL. It's clearly the fault of pedagogy at some stage in the learner's arc. Might this have something to with the only weakly inflected nature of English—when verbs in so many learners' first languages are strongly inflected? I notice now that StoneyB doesn't raise _inflection_ anywhere in his article, and wonder if the article might benefit from its inclusion, particularly for learners from Latinate language backgrounds, or Arabic.